# Weinre remote debugging can't bind to IP

Tags: weinre

I am struggling to get the weinre server up on anything but localhost.

When I try the command `weinre --boundHost -all-` it runs on localhost and the list of boundhost the first two times I tried it only listed localhost and "-all-". But now I am able to get localhost, and the ip address I looked up using `ifconfig` and `ipconfig getifaddr en0`, `192.168.1.121` . However when I try to go to `http://192.168.1.121/` or `http://192.168.1.121:8080/client` on either desktop or phone I don't get anything. Anyone have any success at wetting up weinre?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter name is `--boundHost` **with capital H**.